# ValueError: Attempt to have a second RNNCell use the weights of a variable scope that already has weights

Tags: python, tensorflow

I run `ptb_word_lm.py` provided by Tensorflow 1.0, but it shows this message:

> *ValueError: Attempt to have a second RNNCell use the weights of a variable scope that already has weights:
>   'Model/RNN/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/basic_lstm_cell'; and the cell was
>   not constructed as BasicLSTMCell(..., reuse=True).  To share the
>   weights of an RNNCell, simply reuse it in your second calculation, or
>   create a new one with the argument reuse=True.*

Then I modify the code, add `'reuse=True'` to `BasicLSTMCell`, but it show this message:

> *ValueError: Variable Model/RNN/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/basic_lstm_cell/weights does not
>   exist, or was not created with tf.get_variable(). Did you mean to set
>   reuse=None in VarScope?*

How could I solve this problems?

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me:

```
with tf.variable_scope('rnn'):
    outputs, final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstm_cell, X_in, initial_state=init_state, time_major=False, scope='rnn')
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding `reuse = tf.get_variable_scope().reuse` to BasicLSTMCell is OK to me.

Answer (score 0):

It's modify lstm_cell() as follows:

```
def lstm_cell():
    if 'reuse' in inspect.signature(tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell.__init__).parameters:
        return tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(size, forget_bias=0.0,
                                     state_is_tuple=True, 
                                     reuse=tf.get_variable_scope().reuse)
    else:
        return tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(
                                     size, forget_bias=0.0, state_is_tuple=True)
```

My Environment:

*Windows 10_x64*

*tensorflow-gpu: 1.1.0*

*test is OK.*

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following line on top of your code:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can trying to add `scope='lstmrnn'` in your `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn()` function.

Comment: You don't need to repeat another's answer.  Just upvote their answer or comment on it.